# Differenence between ways to declare functions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods

I have seen some code declaring functions as seen below. What is the difference between `fun1` and `fun2`?

```kotlin
interface Test {
    fun fun1() : Boolean = false
}

fun Test.fun2() : Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fun1` defined inside the interface describes an open function that any implementer of the interface can override. Since it also defines a default implementation by returning something, it is not abstract and implementing classes can choose not to override it.

`fun2` is an extension function. When these are used with interfaces, often the reason is to discourage overriding. An extension function cannot be overridden, but it can be hidden by another extension function with the same signature, but only in a specific scope. Therefore, some implementer of `Test` in another module that passes its instance back to this module cannot change the functionality of `fun2` as used in this module.

Answer (score 0):

The second version is an extension function.

The difference is that extension functions can be applied to any type (even outside of your code), but they do not have access to private members of that type. They are pretty much the same as calling function with this type as a first parameter, just nicer syntax